# How to to make collapsible list/content in webview

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am making an app that displays some local HTML content that are displayed through a webview. I wanted to create collapisble lists and content so not to drown the user in too much text.

I was hoping of something similar that wikia.com uses in their mobile site. As an example here is one of their XCOM articles: http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/XCOM_Hero (Note, it has to be viewed from mobile)

1. What are the different options for this?
2. What would be the simplest way of doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your content is HTML, then you'll be using javascript to make your content interactive. The fact that it'll happen to be displayed on mobile is not particularly relevant to solving your problem.

jQuery UI provides the [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) control, which could be a starting point.